# É possível registrar domínios .go?

Tags: domínio

Então pessoal, alguém sabe se é possível registrar algo como dominio.go?

Pesquisei e não encontrei nada a respeito.

Comment: Creio que não, não achei também e nem nessa lista https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains

Comment: Apesar de já existir uma possível resposta para esta pergunta na 'secção de respostas' abaixo, acredito que esta pergunta se enquadraria melhor em: [webmasters.stackexchange.com](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 5):

A lista de *Top-Level Domains* (TLDs, ou domínios de nível máximo) é gerenciada por uma entidade chamada ICANN (*Internet Corporation for Assigned Names and Numbers*) e mantida pela IANA (*Internet Assigned Numbers Authority*), e pode ser verificada [neste link](http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt).

No momento desta resposta, `.go` não está listado como um TLD publicado. Entretanto, o ICANN possui um programa onde entidades podem requisitar novos TLDs.

Recursos:

- [ICANN](https://www.icann.org/)
- [IANA](http://www.iana.org/)
- [Lista de Top-Level Domains](http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt)

Answer (score 2):

Domínios top-level `.go` não existem.

Fonte: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains